# multiple cstarrating not displaying properly within div Yii

Tags: css, yii

Not sure if this a stylesheet problem or what. The cstarratings are mushed together. The picture is actually showing 3 cstarratings into one line.

[image]

Other things I've tried in my css, `display:inline; clear:both;` remove `float:right`
my stylesheet enclosing the cstarrating:

```
.profile-rating-right-content
{
    float:right;position: 
    relative;width:45%;
    display:inline;
    padding-right:5px; 
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

my cstarrating widget is as follows:

```
<div class="profile-rating-right-content">
    <?php $this->Widget('CStarRating', array(
                    'model'=>$data,
                    'attribute'=> 'star',
                    'minRating'=>1 ,
                    'maxRating'=>5 ,
                    'starCount'=>5 ,
                    'allowEmpty'=>false,
                    'ratingStepSize'=>1,
                    'callback'=>'
                function(){
                    url = "index.php?r=user/review/updateStar";
                            jQuery.getJSON(url, {id: '.$data->review_id.', val: $(this).val()}, function(data) {
                                    if (data.status !== "success"){
                            alert("error"); 
    }});}'
            ));?>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think we have enough information to go on. We'd need to see it live or in a JSfiddle/Codepen.

Comment: what is $data? i mean how it is initialized?

Comment: $data is from CActiveDataProvider from view controller

Comment: ok are you using three widgets or just one?

Comment: ok actually i am confused about the $data. please post the code of its declaration, i think problem is in $data

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't a stylesheet problem.

The IDs for each group were the same, so the widget needs

`'name'=>'rating'.$data->id,`